# Python Assistance on sequences

Tags: python-3.x, sequence

Write a short python function that takes a sequence of integer values and determines if all the numbers are different. (That is they are distinct)

Comment: You will have a hard time learning if you don't do your own homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple. What I would do, is subtract every number from each other, If every number is 0, all numbers MUST be the same, others they are different.

```
def sequence():
 numbers1=[25,30,45,67]
 numbers2=[25,30,45,67]
 count=0
 for i in numbers1:
  for i2 in numbers2:
   if i-i2!=0:
      count+=1
 if count==(len(numbers1)*len(numbers2))-len(numbers1):
  print("all numbers are different.")

a=sequence()
```

Here, you have two lists. Both lists must have the same numbers for this to work. The for loops subtract each number from every other number in the other list. Every time the value is not equal to zero, count is incremented. At the end,

`if count is equal to the length of both lists multiplied by each other (which is 16) - the length of one list`,

then all the numbers are different. You must subtract by the length of one list once, because 4 times `i-i2` will be zero, since both lists have the same numbers.

EDIT:
the above is a quick example, but if you wanted the function to be usable, then you would add parameters within the function which you would then use as the numbers within your lists. These parameters would serve as a way for the user to type in the numbers they want to compare if they're different. However, this would end up being limited, what if the user wanted to compare more numbers than what's provided in the parameters. Maybe you could go the next step and find a way round this.

Comment: This is a neat solution, but should never be used in practice as it is both confusing and has O(n^2) runtime.  Use the python builtins.

Comment: @Matt Bryant, you're right, I wouldn't even use this code, even though i wrote it, but the guy did say he was specifically ask to write his own function not a built-in one. And what is an O(n^2) runtime?

Comment: I read it as asking for a function to do it without any specifications on whether builtins were allowed or not, but that would explain why yours got the accept. It measures speed of an algorithm, look up Big-O notation for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`set`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#set).

```
def unique(numbers):
    return len(numbers) == len(set(numbers))
```